# Align buttons at different nesting levels

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an HTML form which has two buttons.
One of the buttons is only displayed when a variable is true(I am using React).

```
<form>
            {this.state.classificationSelected == true
              ?
              <div>
              <ListAddition classification={this.props.categories[this.state.categoryIndex].classes[this.state.classificationIndex]} ref="listAddition"/>
              <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              </div>
              :
              <div></div>
              }
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
    </form>
```

I would like the buttons to be aligned horizontally.
However, they appear one under the other:

[image]

How can I align the two buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form>
        {this.state.classificationSelected == true
          ?
          <div style={{float:'left'}}>
          <ListAddition classification={this.props.categories[this.state.categoryIndex].classes[this.state.classificationIndex]} ref="listAddition"/>
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
          :
          <div></div>
          }
          <button style={{float:'left'}} type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
</form>
```

This should help.

```
    <form>
        {this.state.classificationSelected == true
          ?
          <div style={{display:'inline-block'}}>
          <ListAddition classification={this.props.categories[this.state.categoryIndex].classes[this.state.classificationIndex]} ref="listAddition"/>
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
          :
          <div></div>
          }
          <button style={{display:'inline-block'}} type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
</form>
```

Or this...

**Explanation:**

By default  element has display:block style witch means it has no floating and break line is applied before it.

Comment: I tried the second version. I'm a bit surprised it works. I thought all the elements of the modal will be put on the same line. However, just the buttons were placed on the line and everything else kept its position. Do you know why this happened?

Comment: Yes, By default <div> element has display:block style witch means it has no floating and break line is applied before it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show="expression", and according to your expression you can show and hide that button as per your requirement.
Reference link:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Answer (score 0):

I figured that you're using bootstrap. You can do something like this:

```
<div class="row" >
    <form>
                {this.state.classificationSelected == true
                  ?
                  <div class="col-md-6" >
                  <ListAddition classification={this.props.categories[this.state.categoryIndex].classes[this.state.classificationIndex]} ref="listAddition"/>
                  <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                  :
                  <div></div>
                  }

                  <div class="col-md-6" >
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
                  </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your divs (block-level elements) with spans (inline elements), or remove them altogether.

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>: 
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" ...>Close</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the first button is contained in a block element (`<div>`), they cannot be on the same line. Some possible fixes are:

- Use inline elements such as `<span>`s for your containers
- Remove nesting problem; put everything in the `<div>`s so that the `<div>`s wrap both buttons.

Examples:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</span>
<span></span>
<button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

```html
{this.state.classificationSelected == true
?
<div>
  <ListAddition classification={this.props.categories[this.state.categoryIndex].classes[this.state.classificationIndex]} ref="listAddition"/>
  <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
</div>
:
<div>
  <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
</div>
}
```